# Creating a JFrame / JLabel using Jython syntax

Tags: java, swing, jython, jlabel

I'd like to create a small Java applet that displays a message and a graphic, but done using Jython. Using the code below I get the error message "TypeError: setIcon(): 1st arg can't be coerced to javax.swing.Icon"

Can anyone offer advise as to

1. How I can get this chunk of code working?
2. Where I might find Jython examples that build GUI windows using Java.swing objects?

Many thanks indeed!
-thescoop.

```
#############################
from javax.swing import JFrame;
from javax.swing import *;
from java.awt import *;

jf = JFrame();
jf.setSize(500,500);
jf.setLocation(100, 50);
jf.setTitle('This is the title');
jf.setLayout(FlowLayout());
l = JLabel();
l.setIcon('lena.png');
jf.add(l);
jf.pack();
jf.setVisible(True);
```

#

Comment: If Favonius' answer below solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking the faded green tick next to it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in `l.setIcon('lena.png');` the `setIcon()` method expects an Icon and not a string. The correct way is to create an `ImageIcon` and then use it. For example:

```
ico = ImageIcon('croco.png');
l.setIcon(ico);
```

The `croco.png` is a test image on my system.

Comment: Favonius,It worked.
Thanks very much indeed , I spent the best part of 2 days slamming my head against the wall over this… better than an aspirin!

Comment: Note that the current working directory is used when you load the image without specifying the path. This caused me some headache when I passed my Jython script to a Java program located in another folder, but it was solved by fetching the script path from sys.argv[0].